# "The following artifacts could not be resolved" : Maven / Android / Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven

I am trying to run an `android` application in `Eclipse` using `Maven` .
Some `dependencies` are unfortunately stopping the run (could not be found or resolved). 
I have already checked that I have the dependencies in my repository.
Any suggestion is welcome.
Thank you for your time and consideration.

**Pom.xml :**

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.2_r2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>android.support</groupId>
        <artifactId>compatibility-v4</artifactId>
        <version>19.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Console's error message:**

```
The following artifacts could not be resolved: android:android:jar:4.4.2_r2, android.support:compatibility-v4:jar:19.0.1: Failure to find android:android:jar:4.4.2_r2 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
```

Answer (score 1):

The android:android:jar:4.4.2_r2 does not exist in your repository. Check really if it exists.

Comment: you mean locally ? it will not download , if it is not there ?

Comment: Locally if you use a local repository. You can see the repository in maven settings.xml file.

Comment: I have them both locally. One is under `home\.m2\repository\android\support\compatibility-v4\19.0.1` , the second under `home\.m2\repository\android\android\4.4.2_r2` .

Answer (score 1):

Due to legal problems, Google do not allow Android JAR files to be installed on the Maven Central repository. You need to manually install these dependencies in your local repository.

To do this you need to clone and execute the [Maven Android SDK Deployer](https://github.com/mosabua/maven-android-sdk-deployer).